# Extract type information from return result of a function

Tags: typescript

I have below function ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ7ABQEoBciBKAphHAE4AmAPAM5SkxgDmANIrfUwHyIDeAsACgAkKUJQQpJP2FCADqTiyAjHgBEAQ1XNBiXYnmKATGoBGqwUIC+g6wMFRUswogCyqACqPnAXgJiJYJ5OlA5OcMAo6JwA3IKCQA)):

```
function myf(): Record<string, string> {
    return {
      prop1: "a",
      prop2: "b"
    }
}
```

The function is pure and just returns dictionary value. I need a type definition extracted from the return type of the function, i.e. `{prop1: string, prop2: string}`. 
When I use

```
type MyType = ReturnType<typeof myf>;
```

it gives me generic `{[key: string]: string}` type, which is correct, but not what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

When I use my function without return type like below ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=39#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ7ABQEpEG8CwAUAJABOAplCKUgScQA6lwMCMAXIgEQCGXANEUTDETFgCZOXAEZcixAL5ElhIlFQNyiALKoAKhq0BeRACVK1MAc0AedZrjAU6AHwBuIkSA)):

```
function myf() {
    return {
       prop1: "a",
       prop2: "b"
    }
}
```

Then it produces valid result:

[image]

However, in that case, I don't have type checking in my return value.

Is it possible to have both type checking in return value and somehow infer return type outside of that function? I.e. I want something like below (but with intellisense for `myvar`)

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem in the second case. Could putting `{prop1: string; prop2: string}` as a return type fix the problem ?

Comment: Sure it will fix the problem, but I don't want to introduce a separate return type, because I have a feeling, that I can somehow infer that type using the TypeScript type system. Potentially I might have a lot of similar functions, all return different objects, return objects are changing during development time, thus I don't want to fix return type definition every time I add\delete\change property on a return object. Instead, I would like to have a return type to be inferred automatically.

Comment: IMO, if you don't want to introduce a separate return type, juste don't write the return type and let typescript infer it

Comment: Then I lose type checking in the return value, as I described in the question :).

Comment: But what do you want to check in your function ?

Comment: For example, below should be invalid: 
`return {
  prop1: "a" // string,
  prop2: 3 // number, error
}`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you add a return annotation `: Record<string, string>` to your function `function myf(): Record<string, string> {` any type inference will *always* give you `Record<string, string>`.

## Recommendation

What you already know, To get the type that is actually returned you can let TypeScript infer it:

```
function myf() {
    return {
        prop1: "a",
        prop2: "b"
    }
}

// Now its {prop1: string, prop2: string}
type MyType = ReturnType<typeof myf>;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was one of my initial attempts, but as indicated in the question, using the suggested approach I lose type-checking inside the function, i.e. I can't check that the value of `prop1` is a string, because it simply accepts anything. Also for such types as `Record<string, IMyData>` I lose intelisense in return type for the same reason.